# Where can I see votes cast and by type in my profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, voting

[image]

Where can I see a description of my votes cast like shown in the screenshot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find them at the bottom right of your activity tab - the tab which opens by default if you open your [own profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current). For other users, the profile page opens on the profile summary and you have to select the 'activity' tab first.

[image]

You've posted quite an old screenshot, you see it looks a bit different nowadays ...

If you want to see all votes instead, use the ['Votes' tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes):

[image]

Comment: is that on stackexchange

Comment: It's on all sites.